# Case insensitive Deserialization

Tags: c#

I have an XML file where

We have defined classes to serialize or deserialize XML.

When we deserialize, if the XML contains like below where "**type**" attribute is in upper case, its throwing error like there is an error in xml(2,2) like that.

```
<document text="BlankPDF" name="BlankPDF" type="PDF" path="" />
```

...

```
[DescriptionAttribute("The sharepoint's document type.")]
[XmlAttribute("type")]
public DocumentType Type
{
    get;
    set;
}

public enum DocumentType
{
    pdf,
    ppt,
    pptx,
    doc,
    docx,
    xlsx,
    xls,
    txt,
    jpg,
    bmp,
    jpeg,
    tiff,
    icon
}
```

this is how we have defined the attribute.

**Is it possible to ignore case while deserializing XML?**

Comment: Could you please post the error in its entirety? Also, when posting code, it is good if you use the little 101010 button to format it properly.

Comment: @Banang: Fixed the formatting

Comment: @Merlyn Morgan-Graham: Thanks!

Comment: @Mehendra babu, without seeing the error, it's very hard to know what's wrong, but I'm thinking this might be a case of namespace collision (the name "Type" feels like a possible criminal here). http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164122.aspx

Comment: Your question is unclear because it is the *value* of the attribute which has case problems.

Answer (score 8):

Define the values of the `DocumentType` enumeration in the uppercase or use the standard adaptor property trick:

```
[Description  ("The sharepoint's document type.")]
[XmlIgnore]
public DocumentType Type { get; set; }

[Browsable    (false)]
[XmlAttribute ("type")]
public string TypeXml
{
    get { return Type.ToString ().ToUpperInvariant () ; }
    set { Type = (DocumentType) Enum.Parse (typeof (DocumentType), value, true) ; }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

For attribute you can also evaluate simply "faking the enum"

```
public enum RelativeType
    {        
        Mum,
        Dad,
        Son,
        GrandDad,
// ReSharper disable InconsistentNaming
        MUM = Mum,
        DAD = Dad,
        SON = Son,
        GRANDDAD = GrandDad
// ReSharper restore InconsistentNaming
    }
```

This works in XML Serialization and Deserialization.
Serialization uses the main definitions, while deserialization can work with both.
It has some side effect, especially when or if you enumerate through Enum.Values or similar.
But if you know what you are doing it's effective

Comment: Won't this only work for attribute values (i.e. `type="GRANDDAD"`)? Will it work for attribute names too (i.e. `tYpE="GrandDad"`)? What does the complete example look like?

Answer (score 2):

I think the short answer is no, you can't ignore case in XmlAttributes as they are case sensitive (see this [article](http://www.xmlnews.org/docs/xml-basics.html)).  This means you will run into many problems (of which this is one) if you have documents coming in with mixed case.

If the attribute name *Type* in all the docs are being stored in upper case can you not just change the XmlAttribute to reflect how it is being stored, so change the line to:

```
[DescriptionAttribute("The sharepoint's document type.")] [XmlAttribute("**TYPE**")]
public DocumentType Type { get; set; }
```

Or would that not work?  If not, in the current scenario I'm not sure that there is a solution.

Comment: +1, since XML is case-sensitive.  Doesn't completely answer the question (how), but does direct the enquirer towards the right solution.

Comment: @Merlyn, sorry I realised that so was in mid edit.  In the mean time you've edited the question too, so more of the original code is now visible (at the time the example XML document wasn't even showing)

Comment: I hate it when people downvote, and don't comment so I can fix it =P