# .net XML deserialization: uppercase and lowercase exception

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net, serialization

I'm having some problems to deserialize a XML in .net. This is the error I'm getting:

> The opening tag 'A' on line 72 position 56 does not match the end tag of 'a'. Line 72, position 118.

As you can see, is the same tag, but one is uppercase and the other is lower case. My XML has this structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<translationfile xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" _
                 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <translationtext>
       <es_text>Spanish text</es_text>
       <en_text>English text</en_text>
       <developer_comment>Plain text</developer_comment>
    </translationtext>
    ....
</translationfile>
```

And this is my vb class

```vb
Option Strict Off
Option Explicit On

Imports System.Xml.Serialization

'
'Este código fuente fue generado automáticamente por xsd, Versión=2.0.50727.3038.
'

'''<comentarios/>
<System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "2.0.50727.3038"), _
 System.SerializableAttribute(), _
 System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute(), _
 System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code"), _
 System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType:=True), _
 System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute([Namespace]:="", IsNullable:=False)> _
Partial Public Class translationfile

    Private itemsField As List(Of translationfileTranslationtext)

    '''<comentarios/>
    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("translationtext", _
        Form:=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)> _
    Public Property Items As List(Of translationfileTranslationtext)
        Get
            Return Me.itemsField
        End Get
        Set(value As List(Of translationfileTranslationtext))
            Me.itemsField = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class

'''<comentarios/>
<System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "2.0.50727.3038"), _
 System.SerializableAttribute(), _
 System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute(), _
 System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code"), _
 System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType:=True)> _
Partial Public Class translationfileTranslationtext

    Private es_textField As String

    Private en_textField As String

    Private developer_commentField As String

    '''<comentarios/>
    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute _
        (Form:=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)> _
    Public Property es_text() As String
        Get
            Return Me.es_textField
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            Me.es_textField = value
        End Set
    End Property

    '''<comentarios/>
    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute( _
        Form:=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)> _
    Public Property en_text() As String
        Get
            Return Me.en_textField
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            Me.en_textField = value
        End Set
    End Property

    '''<comentarios/>
    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute( _
        Form:=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)> _
    Public Property developer_comment() As String
        Get
            Return Me.developer_commentField
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            Me.developer_commentField = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

The problem is that both text could contain HTML code. The XML is generated manually by the clients and I cannot change the text inside these tags. Also they could define their owns tags like `<client27tagname>...</client27tagname>`. For example. This is a real case:

```
<translationtext>
    <es_text><p>Nombre</P></es_text>
    <en_text><p>Name</P></en_text>
    <developer_comment>irrelevant text</developer_comment>
</translationtext>
```

When I try to deserialize a XML file, I'm getting the previous error because `<p>` is lower case and `</P>` is upper case. How can I desarialize it correctly without changing the text? Is there any possibility to treat all the text inside these tags as simple string?

This is the code I'm using for deserialize:

```vb
Dim stream As New IO.StreamReader(path)
Dim ser As New Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(GetType(translationfile))
Dim myperfil As New translationfile

myperfil = CType(ser.Deserialize(stream), translationfile) 'This line throws the exception
stream.Close()
```

**UPDATE**

After doing the change suggested by Olivier. This is my class:

```
Option Strict Off
Option Explicit On

Imports System.Xml.Serialization

<System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "2.0.50727.3038"), _
 System.SerializableAttribute(), _
 System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute(), _
 System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code"), _
 System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType:=True), _
 System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute([Namespace]:="", IsNullable:=False)> _
Partial Public Class translationfile

    Private itemsField As List(Of translationfileTranslationtext)

    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("translationtext", Form:=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)> _
    Public Property Items As List(Of translationfileTranslationtext)
        Get
            Return Me.itemsField
        End Get
        Set(value As List(Of translationfileTranslationtext))
            Me.itemsField = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class

<System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "2.0.50727.3038"), _
 System.SerializableAttribute(), _
 System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute(), _
 System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code"), _
 System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType:=True)> _
Partial Public Class translationfileTranslationtext

    Private es_textField As String

    Private en_textField As String

    Private developer_commentField As String

    <XmlIgnore()>
    Public Property es_text() As String
        Get
            Return Me.es_textField
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            Me.es_textField = value
        End Set
    End Property

    <XmlElement(ElementName:="es_text", Form:=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)> _
    Public Property es_HtmlText() As String
        Get
            Return System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(Me.es_textField)
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            Me.es_textField = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(value)
        End Set
    End Property

    <XmlIgnore()>
    Public Property en_text() As String
        Get
            Return Me.en_textField
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            Me.en_textField = value
        End Set
    End Property

    <XmlElement(ElementName:="en_text", Form:=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)> _
    Public Property en_HtmlText() As String
        Get
            Return System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(Me.en_textField)
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            Me.en_textField = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(value)
        End Set
    End Property
       <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form:=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)> _
    Public Property developer_comment() As String
        Get
            Return Me.developer_commentField
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            Me.developer_commentField = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

Comment: before deserialization in XML file replace all : "</P>" with "</p>" :)

Comment: also, check that XML file generation, it is a huge mistake not to control the format of the tags because XML tags are case sensitive most of cases.

Comment: That's not XML, so XML deserialization isn't going to work. You'll have to manually parse the file, for example using XDocument, and use the node `<en_text>`'s `InnerText`, which is in the `Value` property.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/helloworld/archive/2009/04/03/workaround-to-deserialize-true-false-using-xmlserializer.aspx

Comment: XML is case-sensitive (in standard). That means your cade could ignore cases but any other Xml-parser could not. That means only you could work properly with this Xml documets. Think twice !  I think best way is to check xml before deserialization, even at XML creation why some tags have Uppercase ..! ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3975354/2269262

Comment: Thanks for all the coments, as i said, i cannot change the inner text inside <es_text>. The XML is generated by the client and he sends it to my webapi. The client expect to recibe a xml as response and he uses the <es_text> as an id. If I change something inside it, he will not be able to do the match with the response. I'm going try the answer by Olivier, and if it doesn't work, i will have to parse the file manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some test i found a workaround.

1. I get all the text as a simple string
2. I replace all the `<` characters to a default string: `#open_key#`
3. I replace all the `#open_key#es_text>` to `<es_text>`
4. Same for en_text, developer_coment, etc...
5. I save the result to a temporary file
6. I deserialize the temporary file
7. Before doing the response, I replace all the `#open_key#`to `<`

Answer (score 1):

Use [`HttpUtility.HtmlEncode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73z22y6h(v=vs.110).aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396&cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2) to encode your text and `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode` to decode it.

You could create an additional property for this and exclude the original property from serialization.

```vb
'Exclude the original property from serialization
<XmlIgnore()> _
Public Property en_text() As String
    Get
        Return Me.en_textField
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        Me.en_textField = value
    End Set
End Property

'Name the encoding/decoding property element like the original property
<XmlElement(ElementName := "en_text", Form:=XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)> _
Public Property en_HtmlEncodedText() As String
    Get
        Return HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(Me.en_textField)
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        Me.en_textField = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(value)
    End Set
End Property
```

Html encoding will translate the `"<"` and `">"` into `"&lt;"` and `"&gt;"` and thus make the inner tags invisible to XML.

---

**UPDATE**

Mt solution works. I have tested it now. You have probably tested it with an XML still containing the html tags in plain text (`"<p>Name</P>"`). What my code does is to write the html as `"&amp;lt;p&amp;gt;Name&amp;lt;/P&amp;gt;"`. This is what `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode` does. Therefore you must start by writing an XML file using my method. Only then, reading will succeed.

Here is my write test:

```vb
Public Sub WriteTest()
    Dim myperfil As New translationfile With {
        .Items = New List(Of translationfileTranslationtext) From {
            New translationfileTranslationtext With {.en_text = "en test", .es_text = "spanish"},
            New translationfileTranslationtext With {.en_text = "<p>Name</P>", .es_text = "<p>Nombre</P>"}
        }
    }

    Dim writer As New IO.StreamWriter(path)
    Dim ser As New XmlSerializer(GetType(translationfile))
    ser.Serialize(writer, myperfil)
    writer.Close()
End Sub
```

It creates the following XML:

```xml
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translationfile xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <translationtext>
    <es_text>spanish</es_text>
    <en_text>en test</en_text>
  </translationtext>
  <translationtext>
    <es_text>&amp;lt;p&amp;gt;Nombre&amp;lt;/P&amp;gt;</es_text>
    <en_text>&amp;lt;p&amp;gt;Name&amp;lt;/P&amp;gt;</en_text>
  </translationtext>
</translationfile>
```

And here is my read test, which throws **no** exception:

```vb
Public Sub ReadTest()
    Dim myperfil As translationfile
    Dim reader As New IO.StreamReader(path)
    Dim ser As New XmlSerializer(GetType(translationfile))

    myperfil = CType(ser.Deserialize(reader), translationfile)
    reader.Close()

    For Each item As translationfileTranslationtext In myperfil.Items
        Console.WriteLine("EN = {0}, ES = {1}", item.en_text, item.es_text)
    Next
    Console.ReadKey()
End Sub
```

It write this to the console:

```
EN = en test, ES = spanish
EN = <p>Name</P>, ES = <p>Nombre</P>
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. However I copy-paste your code for both properties, es_text and en_text. Same result :( I think i will have to parse it manually.

Comment: What does your serialized text (the XML) contain after this change?

Comment: I have update my previous question to show you how i changed my class. As I said, I get the same exception on the same line.