# XmlElement read as case insensitive C#

Tags: c#, xml, xmlserializer

I am using XmlSeriazlier to deserialize xml file.

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
using (var reader = document.CreateReader())
   var result = (T)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
```

Xml can contain elements with different casing.
Sample

```
<Layers>
    <Layer name="something" />
    <Layer name="anything" />
    <layer name="nothing" /> ====> 'l' instead of 'L'
</Layers>
```

Now my class is like this.

```
public class Layers
{
    [XmlElement("Layer")]
    public List<Layer> Layers { get; set; }
}
```

Now this will not read 'layer' from the xml. How I can read all xml elements and save them in one list.

Comment: Xml is case sensitive, so why not just make sure that the Xml file is correct in the first place?

Comment: @Sean Old legacy xmls which cannot be changed. So have to support these.

Comment: Related: [Case insensitive XML parser in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9334771/3744182), [Deserialize/Read xml when casing of elements is inconsistent.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45776598/3744182).

Comment: Another option would be to create an XmlReader [decorator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) as shown [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Xml/System/Xml/Core/XmlWrappingReader.cs) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t2abc1zd(v=vs.71).aspx) (under *Chaining XmlReaders*) then subclass the decorator and normalize the case all the element and attribute names.

Answer (score 0):

You could make your `Layer` class inherit `IXmlSerializable` and implement something like the below code in your `ReadXml` implementation:

```
while (!reader.EOF)
{
    // Use string.Compare with StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase to ignore case
    if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && string.Compare(reader.Name, "Layer", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        // reading code
    }
    else
    {
        reader.Read();
    }
}
```

Note that I haven't test the code, but this might be an approach to your problem.